# Unable to call a function in DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Unable to call a DLL "sdm00.dll" which is in SCALE folder.I m trying to invoke "SpC" function which takes  parameter as a "number" converted into asci code+"SpApp|".But m nt able to load DLL & invoke function.PLZ help

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  
typedef string (__cdecl *MYPROC)(string);   

char asc(int a)
{  
    char var;  
    var = (char)a; 
    return var;  
}  

int main()   
{   
    char z;  
    z = asc(20);     
    string str1;  
    string str2;  
    string str3;  
    string retval;     
    str1 = z;  
    str2 = "SpApp|";  
    str3 = str1 + str2;  

    HINSTANCE hinstLib;   
    MYPROC ProcAdd;   
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;  

    // Get a handle to the DLL module

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("c:\\SCALE\\sdm00.dll"));   

    //If the handle is valid, try to get the function address

    if (hinstLib != NULL)   
    { 
        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "SpC"); 

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
            cout << "Function is called" << endl;
            string MyRetValue;
            MyRetValue = (string)(ProcAdd)(str3); 
            cout << MyRetValue << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Function cannot be called" << endl;
        }

        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (!fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Does the `LoadLibrary` call fail? Some other function? If a system function like `LoadLibrary` fails, use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error code.

Comment: Also, does the function you want to call really take a `std::string` as argument, or e.g. `LPCSTR`?

Comment: Provide more info, question is not clear.

Comment: If i simply write LoadLibrary("sdm00.dll"),then program compile & run,bt in command prompt it gives an unreadable error..sumthing..sumthing..bt in middle gives "rtcdll.dll" error & MyProgram.exe error comes in pop-up window. But if i give DLL path in LoadLibrary("C:\SCALE\sdm00.dll"), then else part printed i.e "Message printed frm executables" means it didn't load the DLL. Joachim Pileborg sir, how & where could i use GetLastError in my program.I m new to DLL,Please Guide me& also say whether my above program is ok to load DLL explicitly or not.

Comment: My Senior has made sdm00.dll & "SpC" in Delphi Language.So i think that SpC take LPCSTR.But I neither know DELPHI nor know how to convert std::string to LPCSTR.Plz Help me.

Comment: If you can't read the error message, then we may as well all give up.

Comment: Please provide the actual Delphi code for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DLL is usable in Delphi without error, then it most definately DOES NOT take a `std::string` as input or return a `std::string` as output, since Delphi has no concept of `std::string`.  More likely, the function actually takes a `char*` as input and returns a `char*` as output (if it instead takes a Delphi `String` as input and returns a Delphi `String` as output, then you are SOL), eg:

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <iostream>  

typedef char* (__cdecl *MYPROC)(char*);   

int main()   
{   
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("c:\\SCALE\\sdm00.dll"));   
    if (hinstLib == NULL)   
    {
        cout << "Unable to load sdm00.dll! Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    { 
        MYPROC ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "SpC"); 
        if (NULL == ProcAdd) 
        {
            cout << "Unable to load SpC() function from sdm00.dll! Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string str1 = char(20);  
            std::string str2 = "SpApp|";  
            std::string str3 = str1 + str2;  
            std::string retval = ProcAdd(str3.c_str()); 
            std::cout << retval << std::endl;
        }

        FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After compiling it gives the error at(1) Line 31:Invalid conversion of 'char' to 'const char*'.(2)Line 31:initializing argument1 of std::basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,Alloc>::basic_string(const_CharT...).(3).Line 34:invalid conversion from 'const char*'to 'char*' .Please Help me,how to come out of this problem

Comment: after editing the program at line 31:std::string str1 =(const char*) char(20); & at line 34:std::string retval =ProcAdd(( char*)str3.c_str());it compiled and in Run,it gives the Command prompt with blank output with same window pop-up error "MyProgram.exe" has encountered problem and need to close.Plz say wt i edited at Line 31&34 is it correct? & if it is,thn Y this program is nt able to load Delphi Dll "sdm00.dll",by invokin a "SpC" function.Neither it is showing DLL is not loaded.Wt kind of problem my windows is getting.Plz can any1 figure it out & HELP me.

Comment: `std::string str1 =(const char*) char(20);` is not valid because you cannot type-cast a `char` to a `char*`. `char(20)` is a space character, so you can use `std::string str1 = " ";` or `std::string str1 = "\x20";` instead. You do not need to type-cast `str3.c_str()` since it already returns a `char*`. If you are still having problems, then please provide the actual DLL, or at least the working Delphi code so someone can convert it to the correct C++ code.

Comment: ,if i edited as above at line31:std::string str1="\x20" and at Line34:[left same as]std::string retval =ProcAdd(str3.c_str());\Then compilation error shows at Line 34:invalid conversion from 'constchar*'to'char*'.Dear Ma'm My seniors are able to connect delphi-written "SpC"function in "sdm00.dll" in VB-2003,2006etc & tht working well.My seniors also notified to invoke this"SpC" fn,we hv to gv number[converted into ASCI value]+"SpApp|" &if char(20) denotes char space,thn is this parameter is properly invoking the"SpC" fn which tks onlyASCI converted number+"SpApp|"?HELP me further.

Comment: Change the input parameter of `MYPROC` to `const char*`, then `str3.c_str()` will work. Again, please show the actual Delphi/VB code that works.

Comment: Mam' THANKZ.I got the OUTPUT successfully & Invoked "SpC" fn.THANKS a LOT to U all.